# Why is SignInAsync asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-identity

In the new Identity template code, the controller code that signs in a user is wrapped in an `async` block:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() 
                                   { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, 
                                    await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
}
```

But all of the calls to SignInAsync simply `await` the task completion.  So what's the point of the additional overhead and complexity of making the sign-in code asynchronous?  Or is that a mystery left to the minds of the folks who created the template who may have envisioned some sort of asynchronous sign-in scenario?

EDIT: Ok, there seems to be a bit of confusion as to what I'm asking.  Let's try this:

Why create an asynchronous SignInAsync function when all of the calls to the function are effectively synchronous:

```
await SignInAsync()
```

The async function would make sense if the caller did some other work before `await`ing, but that's not the case...

Comment: Async is the new golden hammer. It seems that sample is meant to handle websites with very high traffic... Or maybe the SignIn/Out process is _that_ inefficient

Comment: yeah but... unless there is some magic in the await/async stuff, the controller just blocks and the asynchronous task runs at the same priority as the controller thread.  How does that help the server handle more traffic?

Comment: @AD.Net in what way is it not asynchronous?

Comment: Everyone is missing the `await` that is in there.. if you scroll right.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see the await

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why create an asynchronous SignInAsync function when all of the calls to the function are effectively synchronous

You say this, but then give an example of an *asynchronous* call.

So, I think the confusion is around the difference between *synchronous* and *sequential*. Consider the code in question:

```
await SignInAsync();
```

This is an *asynchronous* call. The method it's in will be evaluated *sequentially* because it immediately `await`s the returned task, but that does not make it *synchronous*. It's still asynchronous.

You can think of "sequential" as "one step at a time"; this is in contrast to "concurrent", which does multiple things at a time. "Asynchronous" can mean "doing some operation without blocking", whereas "synchronous" means "using the calling thread for the duration of the operation".

Async and await enable asynchronous sequential code (and also asynchronous concurrent code, if you use something like `Task.WhenAll`).

Comment: Oh! Ok, I hadn't noticed that all of the `await`s are, themselves, in `async` code.  (I also didn't understand that all of the async/await magic happens on the same thread.)  And, yes, I didn't understand that `await SignInAsync();` is asynchronous.  But now that I understand `async`, I notice that all of the controller actions that contain an `await` are themselves marked as `async`.  Obviously some magic in ASP.NET figures out whether an invoked action is synchronous or asynchronous and calls it appropriately?

Comment: The "magic" is simply looking at the controller action's return value and seeing whether it's `Task` or `Task<T>`. If it is, then it's treated asynchronously. BTW, `async`/`await` does not actually happen on the same thread; by default they sync back to the same *request context*. You may find my [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` is `async` because the synchronous variant blocks waiting for IO. This is especially bad on the server as while the thread is blocked it could be serving another request. Asynchronous code on the server improves scalability. On the client, it improves UI/Website responsiveness.

When you `await` something, the generated state machine returns immediately after kicking off the operation and then executes the remainder of the method on the same `SyncrhonizationContext` after the asynchronous operation completes. So all you are avoiding is having your thread blocked by some IO operation.

This additional complexity is well worth it, it will make your client more responsive and your server more scalable.